# How to use Trident Animation Library Samples

Tags: java

I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to use the Trident Animation Library sample code. I've downloaded their archive (located at [here](https://kenai.com/projects/trident/downloads/directory/version%201.3%20-%20stable)), trident-all.zip, which has sample code that I would like to run. I imported it as an archive file into one of my Projects where I have added to the build path the two other files, trident.jar and trident-tst.jar. However, whenever I try to compile and run one of their source files, I always get an "Editor does not have a main type" alert. I realize that this is because after importing the trident-all.zip, I had a folder named "src" but it's not a source folder. I right-clicked it and made it a source a folder but this just made more trouble than good.

I can't find any tutorials on how to do these things. I believe there is some way to import the trident-all.zip properly so that it would be properly arranged and the folder named "src" would actually be a source folder without any error. I hope you guys can enlighten me about this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: trident-all.zip does not contain any class files

Comment: you should use trident.jar. The author has just put the .java and not the .class files in the trident-all file

Comment: I forgot to say that I'm using Eclipse. 

How do I use the .jar there? I imported the .jar to the project build path but I can't figure out how to run the sample classes.

Answer (score 1):

Silly me. I kept trying to compile it but soon realized that these files are already compiled. I just opened up the context menu and ran the application and it worked.

Also if it would be help to others, just downloading the .jar files would leave you with no source code. I know not all people need the source code since Java boasts of abstraction. However, if you *do* need it because you want to study a library like Trident, just download the zip file with all the .java and attach the source to the class file when you open it. Just doing it with one class file will attach all the other source files to the other class files.

Cheers.

Comment: the trident.jar is the compiled src, which you should add as a library to your project. If you want to attach source (for debugging purposes) then you need the trident-all.zip. But trident-all.zip is not necessary to run the program :)